# Objective-C delay action with blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I know that there are several ways of delaying an action in Objective-C like:

```
performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:
```

or using `NSTimer`.

But there is such a fancy thing called blocks where you can do something like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.50 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState) animations:^{

    }completion:^(BOOL finished){
}];
```

Unfortunately, this method applies only to animating things.

How can I create a delay with a block in *one method* so I don't have to use all those `@selectors` and without the need to create a **new separate method**? Thanks!

Comment: Will this help you ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218861/call-function-only-after-reloaddata-has-finished/15218941#15218941

Comment: why do you afraid of creating a separate method ? this will solve the problem immediately.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor because I have a lot of methods already and I wanted to find a better way

Comment: i dont sure it will work but you can try calling methods inside completion:^(BOOL finished){
} block

Comment: Is your problem a warning or error you're not mentioning here?

Comment: @StevenFisher the problem is written in the end of the post

Comment: Ah, my problem was just that I misread your code sample. :) You discovered things in a very strange order, but this is a good question. Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

use dispatch_after:

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //code to be executed on the main queue after delay
    [self doSometingWithObject:obj1 andAnotherObject:obj2];
});
```

Comment: well it improves readability a lot - especially when you use blocks as method parameters

Comment: It would be nice to hide this (especially `popTime` calculation) in a function/method, e.g `[NSObject performBlock:afterDelay:];`

Answer (score 25):

Expanding on the accepted answer, I created a Helper function for anyone who doesn't care to memorize the syntax each time they want to do this :) I simply have a Utils class with this:

Usage:

```
[Utils delayCallback:^{
     //--- code here
} forTotalSeconds:0.3];
```

Helper method:

```
+ (void) delayCallback: (void(^)(void))callback forTotalSeconds: (double)delayInSeconds{

     dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
     dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
           if(callback){
                callback();
           }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 11.3.1 (at least, and also other versions of Xcode) provides a code snippet to do this where you just have to enter the delay value and the code you wish to run after the delay.

1. click on the `+` button at the top right of Xcode.
2. search for `after`
3. It will return only 1 search result, which is the desired snippet (see screenshot). Double click it and you're good to go.

[image: screenshot illustrating how to get the snippet from within Xcode itself]

Comment: Wow! The crazy stuff you find hidden in XCode!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can trigger a block after a delay in Swift:

```
runThisAfterDelay(seconds: 4) { () -> () in
    print("Prints this 4 seconds later in main queue")
    // Or just call animatedMyObject() right here
}

/// EZSwiftExtensions
func runThisAfterDelay(seconds seconds: Double, after: () -> ()) {
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), after)
}
```

Its included as a standard function in my repo:
https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions

Comment: Wrong language. Question was about Obj-C