# Objective-C delay a method in iOS 6 dispatch_get_current_queue deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `dispatch_after()` and `dispatch_get_current_queue()` to delay a method at the moment. For example, delay for 1 second:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
        [self someMethod];
    });
```

As `dispatch_get_current_queue()` is deprecated from iOS 6, is there any other equivalent way to do this without creating another separated method for `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`?

A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413014/objective-c-delay-action-with-blocks) but still using the deprecated way. Thanks!

EDIT:

From Peter Segerblom's answer:

```
// Without updating UI
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"Hello World");
});

// updating UI    
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
});
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you should use `dispatch_get_global_queue()` instead. It should do about the same i think. If you are only interested in delaying the method and not running in another que you could just use `dispatch_get_main_queue()`. Just remember that you can't update user interface if you are not in the main que.

Comment: Thanks, both `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)` and `dispatch_get_main_queue()` work perfectly.